# acpi thinks I have two batteries in my laptop?

Tags: power-management, battery

While I was debugging my i3blocks battery monitor, I found that acpi says I have two batteries, when I only have one.

```
>acpi
Battery 0: Discharging, 95%, 10:27:32 remaining
Battery 1: Discharging, 0%, rate information unavailable
```

I could get around this by setting it to detect only battery 0, but they keep randomly switching numbers. Any help?

(Ubuntu 18.04.3, XPS13, i3 gaps)

Comment: Battery 0 battery 1 doesn't mean you have two batteries

Comment: update: battery 1 and 0 just randomly switched labels again. I think it may have something to do with closing the lid?